# Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'app' - Heroku deploy

Tags: python, heroku, webapi

Estoy queriendo subir a Heroku una app de un modelo de ML. Lo pruebo local y funciona, pero al querer hacer el deploy falla indicando que no encuentra la app. Pero si está...
¿hay algo más que me este faltando?

**PROCFILE**

web: gunicorn app:app

**Carpeta de app**

[image: Carpeta de la app]

y este es el log de heroku
[image: Log heroku]

Ya revise la documentación de Heroku y varios articulos de Stackoverflow pero no logro ver donde fallo. ¿alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví!
Despues de ver algunos post sobre los archivos .py.. Descubri que Jupyter permite hacerlo exportando el archivo .ipynb desde Jupyter como "executable script" y se convierte a .py. De este modo Gunicorn detecta el "attribute" app.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: y eso por que lo soluciona ??? es un requisito o que ??? y de que documentacion extrajiste esa respuesta??? deberías mejorar tu respuesta  ... con esos datos...